# How to check If model change after assign clone

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

My model class inherit from BaseModel class. I send my model clone to dialogbox, before that I captured all properties from this model. Than, I open dialog box editing data. If I click save I overwrite model by model clone, otherwise I click close and close dialog. After that I can send data to db, but before I  check if something change by method from base model which captured data at start. 
The problem is that when I assign clone model to orginal model, OnPropertyChange method doesnt invoke and for example: if model clone have collection property and I change something at colection I invoke chollectionChange method at Dialog box and isDataChange method can return true here.  When I assign clone to orginal model, than IsDataChange method return false. I understend that but how can I resolve this problem? Is someone who understand me? :)

Maybe, I shouldnt make clone ? I use observablleColection so I can track changes. I dont know how to implement it. I invoke chollection change event and what's next?

Comment: please be precise: model or viewmodel(since you bind it to the view)?

Comment: I have main view with model and context(viewModel) and I invoke dialog box (UserControle) from it with some properite from model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to use Json.Net to create a json object of your model, and then create a json object again, and compare the strings.

Keep in mind that this is NOT an effecient way to do this, but for your scenario CPU usage should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could set each property instead of setting the whole model. At least for the non list properties.

Something like:

```
original.Property1 = clone.Property1;
original.Property2 = clone.Property2;
```

Instead of:

```
original = clone;
```

Comment: Can a `Clone` be that clever if OP did not copy one by one? and what about other reference types?

Comment: you're right @LeiYang I use Clone method to clone everything what i need, collection , reference types etc.